# how to create a .dat file in java

Tags: java, file, file-io

I want to create a `.dat` file in java which doesn't exist. I don't know how to manually create it either. I know that the following code:

```
 File f = new File(file);
```

is  used for the file, but what exactly is the code for a file which doesn't exist. In other words create a new file.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A statement like `File f = new File(file);` will not create a file on disk. Class `java.io.File` only represents a file path, not the actual file on disk.

To create a new file, open a `FileOutputStream` for it, which you can then use to write data to the file.

```
OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("C:\\Temp\\filename.dat");
try {
    // Write data to 'out'
} finally {
    // Make sure to close the file when done
    out.close();
}
```

Comment: won't it throw FileNotFoundException?

Comment: No, FileOutputStream will create the file. FileInputStream will throw an exception.

Comment: You could also skip the finally block with close if you use the try-with-resources added in Java 7, like so:

`try(OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("C:\\Temp\\filename.dat")
{
    // Write data to 'out'
}`

Answer (score 3):

Quite simply:

```
File myFile = new File("your_file.bat");
myFile.createNewFile();
```

Answer (score 1):

Question is a bit unclear, but this will create a new, empty file:

```
  new File("x.dat").createNewFile();
```

If you want to have some data in it, use a FileOutputStream to the file (which will also create it if missing, overwrite if already there).

Answer (score 1):

Before creating file you should also check whether is really does not exist.

```
File file = new File("abc.dat");
if(!file.exists())
{
    boolean created = file.createNewFile();
}
```